# Error updating packages (0.4)

Tags: git, julia

I'm having trouble pulling/updating packages after removing .julia/v0.4/ due to some permission problems I was having. I was trying to do a fresh install of all of my packages, but now have a problem when trying to update or install packages.

When I run Pkg.update(), after having removed .julia/v0.4:

```
    julia> Pkg.update()

    INFO: Initializing package repository /home/user/.julia/v0.4
    INFO: Cloning METADATA from git://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl
    ERROR: failed process: Process(`git clone -q -b metadata-v2
    git://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl METADATA`, ProcessExited(128)) [128]
```

Any ideas about what's going on here? I should mention that before removing .julia/v0.4 I was also receiving some strange errors, when trying to run Pkg.update().

Update:

After further digging, I believe this has something to do with my git configuration, as I'm behind a firewall. Git is trying to connect to git:// even though I've asked it to use https instead:

```
 git config --get-regexp '^url.*'
 url.https://.insteadof git://
```

git does not seem to recognize my command somehow?

Further Update:

It appears that my version of git was pretty old. After updating to the current version of git, I have no problems connecting to the repository. There must have been a recent change somewhere, as I was able to update packages only last week. Update your version of git if you have similar problems.

Answer (score 3):

In future removing all of the files inside `~/.julia/v0.x` was probably not the best way to go to begin with. `Pkg.resolve()`, which installs the packages, uses the the REQUIRE file which inside this folder as it has the names of all of all the packages to install (or keep installed). You will need to create this again!

In terms of the git issue that you might be having then try:

`git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://`

to use the https protocol or if you end up installing julia v0.5 (the latest release as of Sept '16) then you can use this as well (which will leave your global git settings unaffected):

`setprotocol!("https")`

Comment: I did not know about this new feature for 0.5. Thanks.